# Problem about website with multi-language with html, js and json

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm writing my simple website page, and I want my page has multi-language. And here is what i got:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://trash1-stl.glitch.me/body.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://trash1-stl.glitch.me/header.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <header class="header">
                <div class="header-container">
                    <div class="header-left">
                        <a href="/" class="logo" id="hp"></a>
                        <div class="menu"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="header-right">
                        <div class="language">
                            <a class="logo" value="vi" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <img src="https://cdn.glitch.global/fe903a6f-50b0-47e7-ac0b-5135afb92925/flag_vn.png?v=1670855949145" alt="Chuyển sang tiếng Việt" title="Chuyển sang tiếng Việt" class="logo-image">
                            </a>
                            <a class="logo" value="en" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <img src="https://cdn.glitch.global/fe903a6f-50b0-47e7-ac0b-5135afb92925/flag_uk.png?v=1670855969176" alt="Switch to English" title="Switch to English" class="logo-image">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const languageManager = new LanguageManager();
    const initialLanguage = languageManager.getLanguage() || 'vi';
    loadContent(initialLanguage);
    
    const language = document.getElementsByClassName("language");
    language.addEventListener("change", function() {
        const selectedLanguage = language.value;
        languageManager.setLanguage(selectedLanguage);
        loadContent(selectedLanguage);
    });
});

function loadContent(language) {
    const header_logo = document.getElementsByClassName("logo");
    fetch("lang.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        const content = data.all.header.logo[language];
        header_logo[0].innerHTML = `
        <img 
        src="https://cdn.glitch.global/fe903a6f-50b0-47e7-ac0b-5135afb92925/STL.png?v=1670131602976" 
        alt="${content.alt}" 
        title="${content.title}" 
        class="logo-left-image">
        `;
    })
    .catch(error => console.error("Lỗi tải giá trị!: ", error));
};

class LanguageManager {
    constructor() {
        this.storageKey = "selectedLanguage";
    };

    getLanguage() {
        return localStorage.getItem(this.storageKey);
    };

    setLanguage(language) {
        localStorage.setItem(this.storageKey, language)
    };
}
```

lang.json:

```
{
    "all": {
        "header": {
            "logo": {
                "vi": {
                    "alt": "Content[VN]",
                    "title": "Content [VN]"
                },
                "en": {
                    "alt": "Content [EN]",
                    "title": "Content [EN]"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a code about multi-lang and its keep that type language in other sites (when I choose English (Vietnamese is the defalut language) in `index.html` and its keep set English in `example.html`). And so that, I have a problem: It's said that `language.addEventListener` is not a function`, and I have get correct class name and id in element.

Comment: 1) `getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of elements. 2) Nothing in your HTML will emit a _change_ event. Perhaps you meant to use _click_